# Google Script - Modal dialog - screen freezes after closing the dialog

Tags: google-apps-script

---

I created the following code to create a modal dialog: it is works until it is closed. After closing - the page from where this was called stops responding. Unable to click inside any text box / click any button at all.

> var app = UiApp.createApplication(); var dialog =
>   app.createDialogBox().setModal(true).setText('Record
>   Saved').setPopupPosition(200, 200).show(); var closeHandler =
>   app.createClientHandler().forTargets(dialog).setVisible(false); var
>   button=
>   dialog.setWidget(app.createButton('Ok').addClickHandler(closeHandler));
>   app.add(dialog); return app;

Is there something amiss with that code?

Edit:

I amended the code as follows:

Removed the following line:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
```

Revised code looks as follows:

---

> var dialog = app.createDialogBox().setModal(true).setText('Record
>   Saved').setPopupPosition(200, 200).show(); var closeHandler =
>   app.createClientHandler().forTargets(dialog).setVisible(false); var
>   button=
>   dialog.setWidget(app.createButton('Ok').addClickHandler(closeHandler));
>   app.add(dialog); return app;

The current situation is that the freezing issue is resolved now. The new issue is that the Modal design is gone. The dialog appears at the bottom. Functionality is fine - it is just that modality is gone.

Will continue the search and keep all of us posted. Thank you.

Update:

Improvement in code - hides only the button and not dialog

> var dialog =
>   app.createDialogBox().setModal(true).setPopupPosition(200,
>   200).show(); var closeHandler = app.createClientHandler()
>                            .forEventSource()
>                            .setVisible(false); var savebutton = dialog.setWidget(app.createButton("Record
>   Saved").addClickHandler(closeHandler));

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick. Thanks Team.

> app.createDialogBox().setModal(true).setPopupPosition(200,
>   200).setAutoHideEnabled(true).setText("Record Saved").show();